# Javascript Table to Matrix (Settle Rowspans/Colspans)

Tags: javascript

Im tryng to do something that could be very usefull for some web developers who handle complex table structures.

Lets say i have the following table:

```
   <table id="table" style="width:148.028mm;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>B</td>
         <td>C</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to output this into a matrix

```
[
    [ A , A ]
    [ B , C ] 
]
```

So i can work better with colspans and rowspans. I made an algorithm that `works` for most scenarios, but not all.

Ive found out some really weird scenarios to work with, that ill be demonstrating with this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4k2yw6p6/32/

The goal is to render the bottom table just like the top table, but correctly replicating the cells.

Any idea what am i missing here ?

Comment: can you be more specific about what is your goal? are you trying to parse the html? or you have a data\ metrix \ json in your js file and you want to render a structure like you mentioned

Comment: Tables have their uses, but they're best kept simple with known data to fill them. Developers who handle very complex table structures tend to look at Flex layout / Grid layout nowadays

Comment: Im tryng to generate a matrix that ignores cellspan and rowspan and fills them with information that that cell is a span etc. The fiddle ive made shows a second table as the matrix, just for viewing purporposes. The 'why' of the algorithm here is not questionable, infortunally its needed.